# character encoding output to a file in linux

Tags: character-encoding

The working environment is jboss+mssql

I am doing a query and output the formatted result to a text file. The query result has some French accent characters.

On my local machine, everything works fine, but on the UAT server (linux box, UTF-8), the french accent characters become question marks.

Does anyone know how to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you create your file - a code example would be helpful.

If you do specify an encoding explicitly, e.g. when creating a `Writer`, then if it doesn't match the locale of the machine on which you view the file, you may see question marks, placeholder boxes etc. instead of accented letters. You can use the `locale` command to check your locale and this will make it possible to learn the associated character encoding. This is just a matter of viewing the file. You say that the box is UTF-8, but do ensure that the app is also running under a UTF-8 locale - your user console and the server app may be using different locales.

If you do not specify the character encoding when writing, most often you will end up using the system's locale. In that case it may happen that this locale doesn't support the characters you need, so they are replaced with placeholders. A solution would be to change the locale with which your app is running e.g. by exporting the corresponding `LC_*` environmental variables.

So, the short checklist goes like this:

- How do you write your file? Is the encoding specified explicitly?
- What is the locale with which the app is running (output of `locale` command)?
- Check the actual bytes written to your file using `od -t x1` command or using a hex viewer like the one included in `mc`. Are the question marks actual question marks (hex code 3F), or rather some other character? If they take one byte, they're probably in one of the Latin-N (ISO 8859-N) encodings. If they take more than one byte, it's probably UTF-8 (I understand the letters a-z look normal, so it's not UTF-16).